# Updating prop from child component and re-using it again

Tags: reactjs

(Beginner at React at work, building first app to learn it.)

It's explained better with this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-frost-9rozok?file=/src/components/Pagination.js)

Main component renders a pokemon list and has two `<PokemonBio />` and `<Pagination />` child components. `<PokemonBio />` has `filteredPokemon` prop passed to it which is a filter bound to input, `<Pagination />` has that same prop, but it's only rendered once. How `<Pagination />` works is take the same prop and break it down into `currentPokemons` which is a part of the whole array only shown on the clicked 'page'.

Because `<Pagination />` doesn't re-render, the `filteredPokemon` prop won't update. So inside the `<Pagination />` I thought to emit the `currentPokemons` to the parent component and pass that down as as a prop instead of the `filteredPokemon`, but this is just confusing and doesn't seem efficient. In the end I would like to use the input and pagination on the same data. I'd appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: hey I fixed your pagination glitch, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-violet-gom9h2?file=/src/components/Pagination.js) also I had to fix IDs in pokemondata.js
let me know your thoughts

Comment: Hi thanks for taking a look, I see you've made some changes to the pagination but I can't tell that it's fixed? Searching for pokemon and the pokemon that's output within the pagination should both use the same prop. So if there are like 10 pokemon, they'd be paginated, but you could also search for them by typing which would spread it across fewer pages or even 1 page if it's by searching by name.

Comment: @Zomi got it, you are using props to set state inside pagination component, so when parent states changes, props also changes its value BUT since you passed it as initial state in pagination, it never updates. so use it directly

Comment: and here is updated [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-mirzakhani-x9x959?file=/src/components/Pagination.js)

Comment: I very much appreciate this! I see that you used componentDidUpdate for this, at one point I tried componentDidMount but I couldn't make progress. I can now happily continue learning React with this pokemon app. I wish I could reward you the correct answer, so if you can place it as an answer I will happily do so, but i'll leave it to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so there were multiple issue, main one being passing props to state. So when props value changes it wont reflect on state. To solve this either you have to update state whenever props changes using `componentDidUpdate` or consume prop directly which is best option.
Others were like items with same Id, looping over same thing twice & logic issues.

Final solution can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-mirzakhani-x9x959?file=/src/components/Pagination.js)

*I quite enjoyed this, dealing with pagination is not easy.*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the render key, you should change the "id" on the PokemonData page so each pokemon has a unique id.

Comment: It's true that I had a separate issue with the ids there (which I fixed now, so thank you) but I think it's unrelated to the issue of being able to search through the same data and having pagination use the same prop

Comment: Actually it's a bit confusing, why are you using functional component all over the app and just on the pagination.js using class component? Try to make it all functional component and if it wont work send me again the codesandbox, ill figure it out

Comment: I will, and thanks for the tip! I'm still learning React so I didn't know when to use a class component but I figured out what I have so far using it.

Comment: Actually it looks good for a beginner, good job. just stick to one method imo, either use functional or class (i think functional is more relevant nowadays)